# Manually calculating delta time

Tags: c++, arduino, timedelta

I'm trying to learn how to manually calculate delta time (the time since the last game loop update), but I must be misunderstanding something somewhere. I'm doing this for an Arduino project, but it's equally applicable to any language or platform I guess.

I defined the variables `oldTime`, `currentTime` and `deltaTime` and each game loop I do the following:

```
void loop() {
   oldTime = currentTime;  // Save time from last loop.
   currentTime = millis(); // Time since program began.
   deltaTime = currentTime - oldTime; // Calculate time taken by game loop.
}
```

I then multiply my sprite speeds by deltaTime when using them to translate a sprite. However it's not resulting in a speed that's independent of what is drawing on the screen. When I have a background full of tiles, the speed is quick, but when I don't draw a background at all, the sprite speed is really slow.

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Edit: Adding more info.....The background is simply a tile repeated across the screen. So having the background there will increase drawing time and so should increase deltaTime. All drawing is done at the end of the `loop` function.

Edit 2: I might as well add the whole code.

```
#include <Arduboy.h>
Arduboy arduboy;

const unsigned char background[] PROGMEM = {
  0x81, 0x00, 0x12, 0x40, 0x4, 0x11, 0x00, 0x4,
};
const unsigned char player[] PROGMEM = {
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x34, 0xfc, 0x8f, 0x34, 0x6, 0x36, 0x8e, 0x94, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x2, 0x1e, 0xe6, 0xa3, 0xda, 0x83, 0xc4, 0xb8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
};

int playerX;
int playerY;

unsigned long currentTime = 0;
unsigned long oldTime = 0;

void setup() {
  arduboy.begin();
  arduboy.clear();
  ResetGame();
}

void loop() {
  oldTime = currentTime;
  currentTime = millis();
  unsigned long deltaTime = currentTime - oldTime;

  arduboy.clear();
  for (int i = 0; i < 128; i += 8) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 64; j += 8) {
      arduboy.drawBitmap(i, j, background, 8, 8, WHITE);
    }
  }
  arduboy.fillRect(playerX + 4, playerY, 8, 16, BLACK);
  arduboy.drawBitmap(playerX, playerY, player, 16, 16, WHITE);
  arduboy.setCursor(0, 0);
  arduboy.print(arduboy.eachFrameMillis);
  if (arduboy.pressed(LEFT_BUTTON))
    playerX -= deltaTime;
  if (arduboy.pressed(RIGHT_BUTTON))
    playerX += deltaTime;
  if (arduboy.pressed(UP_BUTTON))
    playerY -= deltaTime;
  if (arduboy.pressed(DOWN_BUTTON))
    playerY += deltaTime;
  if (arduboy.pressed(A_BUTTON) and arduboy.pressed(B_BUTTON))
    ResetGame();

  arduboy.display();
}

void ResetGame()
{
  playerX = 5;
  playerY = 10;
  return;
}
```

Comment: Not enough info, drawing a background must have some side effect, maybe your loop runs each time something is rendered?

Comment: I've added some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I managed to fix it myself. I just changed the character position variables to floats instead of ints and changed the time variables to floats instead of longs. I don't really understand why this fixed things though.